Singularities of hypersurfaces with bounded mean curvature?
I'm looking for references or examples of what type of singularities can occur in the limit of a sequence of hypersurfaces with bounded mean curvature. I.e. suppose $\{Y_i\}$ are each smooth, separating hypersurfaces with uniformily bounded area, $H_{Y_i}$ is a smooth function, and $\sup_i ||H_{Y_i}||_{C^0} \leq C$ uniform in $i$.
By the compactness of integral varifolds, there is a subsequence of $Y_i$ which converge as varifolds to $V$, an integral (?) rectifiable varifold. But can anything more be said using the fact that the $Y_i$ are each smooth hypersurfaces with bounded area and mean curvature? In the opposite direction, how singular could the limit varifold be?
Edit: Assume that $Y_i^n \subseteq M^{n+1}$ with $n+1 \leq 7$ to rule out high codimension singularities of minimal surfaces.
